# History.JS - replaceState appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I am using the History.js framework and I only use the **replaceState** method.

My issue is about the replaceState behaviour, since it replaces all the querystring.

```
History.replaceState(null, null, "?tab=2");
```

So when I run the above code all parameters are erased and **?tab=2** is added :

**www.yoursite.com/accounts?tab=2**

Is it possible to maintain the other parameters unchanged except for the **tab=2**

**www.yoursite.com/accounts?country=1&city=2&tab=2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to build that new querystring yourself.

```
function append(p) {
    return (location.search ? location.search+"&" : "?") + p; // + location.hash
}
history.replaceState(null, null, append("tab=2"));
```